# Double size inverse fourier transform

Tags: fft

This question is about 1-d signals.

I have an array of size X with the signal on which I preform Fourier transformation using FFTW.

Is there a way to use the frequency domain data from this transformation to get an array of size X * 2 that contains the time-domain signal resampled to twice the original sampling frequency?

Would that be the same as doing linear interpolation on the original array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You have an X-length time-domain sequence and an X-length frequency-domain sequence. Then you say you want some mysterious, undefined, sequence whose length is 2X. The 2X-length sequence you desire, is it a time-domain sequence or a frequency-domain sequence? What is the nature of your desired 2X-length sequence, is it 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional? If you clarify your question you'll probably receive a useful answer.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE @SFO!  Please try to clarify your question by editing it so as to answer Rick's questions about what you're really trying to do. It's not clear from what you've written.

Comment: Hey Peter and Richard. Olli answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the spectrum to an array that is long enough to contain the spectrum of the double-length array. Put all the frequencies in their right places so that the zero frequency bin, the negative frequency bins (do not exist if you used real-input-FFT), and the positive frequency bins fall in their correct places. Zero the remaining (high-frequency) bins. If your original array was of even length, depending on the flavor of FFT, you may need to split the Nyquist frequency (highest original frequency, sampling frequency / 2) bin to its identical negative and positive frequency component and divide their value by two. You may further need to scale all bins by a constant (2 in the example) to account for the way the particular FFT and IFFT implementations are normalized. Then at the end use IFFT to get back to time domain (example in Octave):

```
octave:1> x = [1 2 3 4]
x =

   1   2   3   4

octave:2> X = fft(x)
X =

   10 +  0i   -2 +  2i   -2 +  0i   -2 -  2i

octave:4> Y = [10 -2+2i -1 0 0 0 -1 -2-2i]*2
Y =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   20 +  0i   -4 +  4i   -2 +  0i    0 +  0i    0 +  0i    0 +  0i

 Columns 7 and 8:

   -2 +  0i   -4 -  4i

octave:5> y = ifft(Y)
y =

   1.0000   1.0858   2.0000   2.5000   3.0000   3.9142   4.0000   2.5000
```

The process is not equivalent to linear interpolation but to ideal sinc interpolation with wraparound of the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) tails to account for the assumed periodicity of the sequence.